# I cant get my package to compile the way i want to

Tags: java

Im doing a school project, its about a computer shop. Basically the user has to key in what specs they want for a Computer/Laptop. They type in 3 if they want to see what they typed in.

But for some reason i can't get the thing to compile the way i want so i've provided the Main Class. I dont think the other classes have any issues.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class ComputerShop1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int response = 0;
        int desktopCounter = 0;
        int laptopCounter = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Desktop[] dt = new Desktop[5];
        Laptop[] lt = new Laptop[5];

        do{
            System.out.println("************************************* BoBo Co. *************************************");
            System.out.println("Computer Menu: ");
            System.out.println("1. Add information for new Desktop ");
            System.out.println("2. Add information for new Laptop ");
            System.out.println("3. Display all computer information ");
            System.out.println("4. Quit ");
            System.out.println("*******************************************************************************************************");
            System.out.println("Please enter either 1 to 4: ");

            response = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

            if (response <= 0 || response > 4 ){
                System.out.println("Enter a number from 1 to 4 Please : ");
            } else {

                if(response == 1) {

                    dt[desktopCounter] = new Desktop();
                    System.out.println("====================================================================");
                    System.out.println("Information for new Desktop");
                    System.out.println("====================================================================");
                    System.out.println("What is the Desktop Model: ");
                    dt[desktopCounter].setID(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("What is the Processor Speed: ");
                    dt[desktopCounter].setSpeed(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("What is the RAM size: ");
                    dt[desktopCounter].setRAM(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("What is the Harddrisk size: ");
                    dt[desktopCounter].setHDD(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("What is the Monitor Type: ");
                    dt[desktopCounter].setMonitor(scanner.nextLine());

                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Your information has been added successfully");
                    System.out.println();

                    desktopCounter++;
                } else if (response == 2){

                    lt[laptopCounter] = new Laptop();
                    System.out.println("====================================================================");
                    System.out.println("Information for new Laptop");
                    System.out.println("====================================================================");
                    System.out.println("What is the Laptop Model: ");
                    lt[laptopCounter].setID(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("What is the Processor Speed: ");
                    lt[laptopCounter].setSpeed(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("What is the RAM size: ");
                    lt[laptopCounter].setRAM(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("What is the Harddisk size: ");
                    lt[laptopCounter].setHDD(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("What is the Weight: ");
                    lt[laptopCounter].setWeight(scanner.nextLine());

                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Your information has been added successfully");
                    System.out.println();

                    laptopCounter++;
                } else if (response == 3) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < desktopCounter; i++){
                        System.out.println("Desktop" + (i + 1));
                        dt[i].displayInfo();
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0;i < laptopCounter; i++ ){
                    System.out.println("Laptop "+ ( i + 1));
                    lt[i].displayInfo();
                    System.out.println();
                }
                }
            }
        } while (response < 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? What error are you getting?

Comment: What do you mean by *compile the way you want*? Is there an error?

Comment: one of them is, when i enter a number larger than 4, it gives me this response "Enter a number from 1 to 4 Please :", but it follows up with a build successful, even though i want it to prompt the user to key in 1 to 4

Comment: and when i key in 3, nothing shows up

Comment: What does this have to do with code compilation? I think that you don't understand what the term means, and this is resulting in a confusing question. You've got a logical error, not a problem in compilation, meaning it's time for you to do some debugging. If you don't know how, then please read: [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: New to this so im not really sure what errors are what and what some terms are. im really sorry if im not clear in explanations.

Comment: You have a `do (...) while (response < 4)`, so when you input something greater than 4 you print your error message and you stop looping since response isn't lesser than 4. I think you'll want to change that to `while (response != 4)` (while the user hasn't specifically asked to quit with the answer `4`

Comment: I would step through your code in an IDE, and you'll soon find the problem.

Comment: On netbeans and it says  " int response = 0;" Value is never used

Comment: "Value is never used" that's because the first thing you do with variable response, is set it to another value. Setting it to zero in the first place is therefore completely ignored. The compiler is trying to be helpful asking why would you do something ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it have compiled for me and got the output.

```
enter code here

************************************* BoBo Co. *************************************
Computer Menu: 
1. Add information for new Desktop 
2. Add information for new Laptop 
3. Display all computer information 
4. Quit 
*******************************************************************************************************
Please enter either 1 to 4: 
1
====================================================================
Information for new Desktop
====================================================================
What is the Desktop Model: 
sdfsdf
What is the Processor Speed: 
23
What is the RAM size: 
500
What is the Harddrisk size: 
500
What is the Monitor Type: 
sony

Your information has been added successfully

************************************* BoBo Co. *************************************
Computer Menu: 
1. Add information for new Desktop 
2. Add information for new Laptop 
3. Display all computer information 
4. Quit 
*******************************************************************************************************
Please enter either 1 to 4: 
3
Desktop1
Desktop [ID=sdfsdf, speed=23, ram=500, HDD=500, monitor=sony]
```